# How to draw horizontal grid only (using pandas plot + pyplot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I would like to get only horizontal grid using pandas plot.

The integrated parameter of pandas only has `grid=True` or `grid=False`, so I tried with matplotlib pyplot, changing the axes parameters, specifically with this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax2 = plt.subplot()
ax2.grid(axis='x')
df.plot(kind='bar',ax=ax2, fontsize=10, sort_columns=True)
plt.show(fig)
```

But I get no grid, neither horizontal nor vertical. Is Pandas overwriting the axes? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try setting the grid **after** plotting the DataFrame. Also, to get the horizontal grid, you need to use `ax2.grid(axis='y')`. Below is an answer using a sample DataFrame.

I have restructured how you define `ax2` by making use of `subplots`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'lab':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'val':[10, 30, 20]})

fig, ax2 = plt.subplots()

df.plot(kind='bar',ax=ax2, fontsize=10, sort_columns=True)
ax2.grid(axis='y')
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you can also do the following: Use the axis object returned from the DataFrame plot directly to turn on the horizontal grid

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax2 = df.plot(kind='bar', fontsize=10, sort_columns=True)
ax2.grid(axis='y')
```

**Third option** as suggested by @ayorgo in the comments is to chain the two commands as

```
df.plot(kind='bar',ax=ax2, fontsize=10, sort_columns=True).grid(axis='y')
```

[image]

Comment: To move the y-grid lines to the back, add the `zorder=0` to the arguments when calling `grid`

Comment: The zorder=0 argument did not work for me

Comment: Try zorder=-1 or less

Comment: This worked for me when zorder didnt: `ax.set_axisbelow(True)`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative: Matplotlib's `plot` (and `bar`) don't draw the vertical grid by default.

```py
plt.bar(df['lab'], df['val'], width=0.4)
```

or using the object-oriented approach:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df['lab'], df['val'], width=0.5)   # plot bars
ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)              # set ticklabel size to 10
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
# pad bars on both sides a bit and draw the grid behind the bars
ax.set(xlim=(xmin-0.25, xmax+0.25), axisbelow=True);
```

[image: res]